# Calling a function in coffeescript from inline script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have defined a function in the coffeescript file as:

```
showAlert = () ->
  alert("asdfsd")
```

And from view i call this function as:

```
:javascript
  jQuery(function(){
   showAlert();
  });
```

But the function is not triggering. What is wrong here?

Comment: Does simply `showAlert()` work?

Comment: @alex yes! when I remove the function and put the code inside jQuery function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Coffeescript automatically wraps its transpiled Javascript output in an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (IIFE), which means any functions you declare within a Coffeescript block are *not* in the global scope. Thus, your jQuery block can't find the `showAlert` function, because it doesn't exist in a scope/closure your jQuery block can access.

What you can do (though I'm not sure it's a great idea) is declare your "global" function on the `window` namespace:

```
window.showAlert = -> alert('asdfasdf')
```

And invoke it from your jQuery block:

```
javascript:
  jQuery(function($){
    window.showAlert();
  });
```

This will work because the `window` namespace is available in all (browser) scopes.